# List of Windows 7 System default colors for controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to match my application's custom controls colors to the ones used in Windows 7. However, I cannot seem to find a complete list of all colors used by Windows 7. Is there a built in class containing these colors, or do I have to use a color picker for every control I want to style.

Comment: +1 for trying to match your application's UI to the current Windows color scheme. I wish more developers would follow suit!

Comment: I, on the other hand, wish developers would stop assuming we all use a default color scheme. ;)  "Floodlight" trimmed with "police lights" and 8hr+ work days make bad bedfellows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does the [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) class help?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must have missed it while searching in the MSDN library

Answer (score 8):

If anyone's interested in seeing the system colours for different themes at a glance, I've created a reference [here](http://www.quppa.net/syscol).

Use these functions and classes and set your application's colours dynamically: GetSysColor function (Win32), System.Windows.SystemColors class (Windows Presentation Foundation), System.Drawing.SystemColors class (Windows Forms).